# C# stream Deserialize way to loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, stream

So I am working on a windows form application and inserting objects into a listbox (sessionListBox). I am creating each object on a different forum and not finalising all the objects to become one. This means when I come to stream/load my saved file it will only load one object. Is there a way you can loop the stream so that it brings back more than one object and how would I go about this ?

Very new to c# and programming so go easy on me if its an obvious solution :)

```
 private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                Stream stream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 
            Console.WriteLine("Writing Workout Information");

            foreach (Workout w in sessionListBox.Items)
            {
                bformatter.Serialize(stream, w);
            }
            stream.Close();
            }

        
    }

private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            Stream stream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            
            

            if (stream.Length != 0)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("");
              Workout temp = (Workout)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
              sessionListBox.Items.Add(temp);
            }
            stream.Close();
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could make life easier for yourself and just serialize the entire array.

Comment: You should serialize and deserialize a `List<T>`, where `T` is a serializable object, `Workout` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only deserialize what you serialized. If you want to serialize an array or a list, put the data in the list, and read the data as a list.

Furthermore: don't try to do everything in your form. Make separate classes to do separate things (read an article about SOLID principle). This will make it way easier to reuse your code, easier to understand, text, debug the code, and easier to change.

So I make a separate class that Stores and Retrieves sequences of Workouts. I hide from the outside world in what format the Workouts are saved. All I know is that the Workouts can be saved, and retrieved, even after the program has been restarted.

```
static class WorkoutRepository
{
    public static void Save(IEnumerable<Workout> workouts, string fileName)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, workouts.ToList());
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<WorkOut> Load(string fileName)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            if (obj is IEnumerable<Workout> workouts)
            {
                return workouts;
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: throw exception?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Workout> workoutsToSave = ...
string fileName = ...

// Save:
WorkoutRepository.Save(workouts, fileName);

// Load:
var workOuts = WorkoutRepository.Load(fileName).ToList();
```

This code is reusable. The nice thing is, that you have hidden in what format you save the data: users (= code, not operator) won't have to change if you decide to save it as an array, or save it in XML format or in a database.

Code is way easier to unit test, and your code will be way easier to understand if you separate your window handling from your serializing.

In your form:

```
IEnumerable<Workout> FetchWorkouts()
{
    using (var dlg = new OpenFileDlg())
    {
        ...
        return WorkoutRepository.Load(dlg.Filename);
    }
}

private void LoadWorkouts()
{
    var fetchedWorkOuts = this.FetchWorkOuts();
    this.ShowWorkOuts(fetchedWorkOuts);
}

private void LoadButton_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.LoadWorkouts();
}
```

By separating the data from where you store and how you display it, it will be easy to change this: Load the workouts on menu selection instead of button click? Show the workouts in a DataGridView instead of a ListBox? Fetch the workouts from a database: always change in one fairly small method that has one precise task.